# NSUserDefaults BOOL returning (null)

Tags: iphone, null, boolean, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to pull an NSUserDefaults value from a Settings.bundle into my application. When I load up the NSUserDefaults on application load, though, an NSLog reveals that my BOOL value returns "`(null)`" and my String value returns the number `39540360`. The weird thing is that the documentation on NSUserDefaults specifically states that

"If a boolean value is associated with defaultName in the user defaults, that value is returned. Otherwise, NO is returned."

So even if the Settings.bundle is not connected (Which I believe to be the case, anyway) it should return NO, right? Regardless, my second part to this question is how would someone call `(null)` as in `if (maxCountEnabled == (null)){` because no nil, NULL, or NSNull method worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is correct, if you create a new empty project and put the following in the delegate `applicationDidFinishLaunching`

```
  NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

  BOOL tst = [defaults boolForKey:@"missingKey"];
```

The value for tst will be NO

Let me know if you are doing something else